# Privacy related style coding - Regarding OOP JS and patterns

Tags: javascript

I have finished multiple courses and books but none of them have talked about paradigms and patterns except one(the udemy travesty media course). Every course except that one didn't bother about privacy at all, they just made public variables, function here, object there, they tried to get the job done, but that's it.

While that one course, coded using IIFEs for privacy, he returned methods so I can access the actual data, he split the work into controllers(modules? He had an Item, UI and APP controller, the project was a calorie tracker thing)

He taught programming JS with objects. Here are a few pictures of the code he wrote https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6wPf.jpg

Now for the actual question, When I get a real job, what will I see? Programming using objects and methods? Or maybe object here, function there? Or both?

Is the way he is writing good? Should I code like that? I tried searching for some OOP JS videos on youtube but I can't really find any, or at least, I can't find any programming the way he does, and the videos of some projects I have watched on youtube, none have coded in such a way.

What should I do? Who should I learn from? What should I learn?

Comment: Take a look at [JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/); Read about [TypeScript classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) and see the resultant _js_ file the _tsc_ (TypeScript Compiler) emits. Advice you to also check good [JavaScript projects in GitHub](https://github.com/trending/javascript)

Comment: your question looks like a rough diamond.."wiki-like" question in the making. It involves question about privacy related style of coding which makes it in certain cases that software will be more robust against malpractice if followed. I vote this should be a "wiki-like" question in the near future.

Comment: Giving advice about live choices is not what SO is about. If you have a specific problem, consider studying [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and your exception / expectation that do not get met by your code and I am sure SO will help you out. This question is Offtopic due to "primarily opinion-based". You will find all this and worse (and better) out in the industry.